# Submit button in HTML table not showing

Tags: php, button, html-table

I'm trying to add a button to the end of a table dynamically populated from a database but when I try to add that simple button I only get a printed text like below in a table td instead the actual button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i><?php echo $field7name ?></button>
```

I know I'm doing something wrong but I really don't know what.

What can I do?

That is what I have for now.

```
<?php 
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM ff_ppomoc WHERE idupor != 0 ORDER BY id ASC";

echo '<table 
       id="table1" 
     data-toggle="table"
             data-search="false"
             data-filter-control="true" 
             data-show-export="false"
             data-click-to-select="false"
             data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-show-columns="false"
       data-checkbox-header="false"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-show-pagination-switch="false"
                    
       data-show-refresh="false"
       data-show-toggle="false"
       data-sort-name="name"
       data-sort-order="desc"
       
       data-actions="edit,remove"
       data-url="index.php"
       >
      
    <thead>
        <tr>
      <th data-field="id"></th>
            <th data-field="dst" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Davčna št.</th>
            <th data-field="davcna" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Ime in priimek</th>
            <th data-field="imepriimek" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Vloga v postopku</th>
            <th data-field="vloga" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Oblika pomoči</th>
            <th data-field="oblikapomoci" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Leto uvedbe postopka</th>
      <th data-field="vsebina" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="false">Vsebina</th>
      <th data-field="moznosti"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>';

        if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($query1)) {
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $row["ime"];
        $field2name = $row["priimek"];
        $field3name = $row["ravenpomoci"];
        $field4name = $row["dst"];
        $field5name = $row["idupor"]; 
        $field6name = $row["vlogavpostopku"]; 
        $field7name = $row["id"]; 
        $field8name = $row["oblikapomoci"]; 
        $field9name = $row["letouvedbepostopka"]; 
        $field10name = $row["povzetek"]; 
       
      ?>
        
        <tr>
           <form action="index.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="'.$field7name.'">
                <td><?php echo $field7name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field4name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field1name ?>  <?php echo $field2name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field6name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field8name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field9name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field10name ?></td> 
                <?php $td1 = $_POST['td_1'] ?>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i><?php echo $field7name ?></button></td>
           </form>
          </tr>
  
      <?php
  
    }
    $result->free();
} 




?>
```

Comment: A form cannot be the child of a `tr` element. It must either encompass the entire table, or be placed inside a single `td`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know iam doing a lot of wrong things. How can i properly add a button in the last td of a table row that posts the ID of the row in another php file?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, per comment from @El_Vanja

This solution moves the form element to outside the table

Additional cleanup:

- Closed the table tag
- moved the hidden field to inside first `td`

```
<?php 
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM ff_ppomoc WHERE idupor != 0 ORDER BY id ASC";

echo '
           <form action="index.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post"><table 
       id="table1" 
     data-toggle="table"
             data-search="false"
             data-filter-control="true" 
             data-show-export="false"
             data-click-to-select="false"
             data-toolbar="#toolbar"
       data-show-columns="false"
       data-checkbox-header="false"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-show-pagination-switch="false"
                    
       data-show-refresh="false"
       data-show-toggle="false"
       data-sort-name="name"
       data-sort-order="desc"
       
       data-actions="edit,remove"
       data-url="index.php"
       >
      
    <thead>
        <tr>
      <th data-field="id"></th>
            <th data-field="dst" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Davčna št.</th>
            <th data-field="davcna" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Ime in priimek</th>
            <th data-field="imepriimek" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Vloga v postopku</th>
            <th data-field="vloga" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Oblika pomoči</th>
            <th data-field="oblikapomoci" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Leto uvedbe postopka</th>
      <th data-field="vsebina" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="false">Vsebina</th>
      <th data-field="moznosti"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>';


        if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($query1)) {
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $row["ime"];
        $field2name = $row["priimek"];
        $field3name = $row["ravenpomoci"];
        $field4name = $row["dst"];
        $field5name = $row["idupor"]; 
        $field6name = $row["vlogavpostopku"]; 
        $field7name = $row["id"]; 
        $field8name = $row["oblikapomoci"]; 
        $field9name = $row["letouvedbepostopka"]; 
        $field10name = $row["povzetek"]; 
       
      ?>
        
        <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="'.$field7name.'">
<?php echo $field7name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field4name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field1name ?>  <?php echo $field2name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field6name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field8name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field9name ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $field10name ?></td> 
                <?php $td1 = $_POST['td_1'] ?>
                <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i><?php echo $field7name ?></button></td>
          </tr>
  
      <?php
  
    }
    $result->free();
} ?>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. but still getting only text instead of the button

Comment: I've edited this several times, so try again with my latest draft. Additionally, this is posted without being able to be tested properly, just ensuring the syntax *appears* correct. The main issue i saw was you're trying to put elements where they're not allowed (ie between `tr` and `td` rather than inside the `td`. It's likely your issue here is with syntax.

Comment: It also occurs to me, although not listed, if you're using some form of CMS,  eg WordPress or Laravel, it may actually be "helping" by cleaning the "scary" HTML tags to protect from injection...

Comment: Now i get this text:  <input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="'.$field7name.'"> in the first field. I cant understand why is printing the text instead of executing the code...

Comment: that is the main issue. when i put a code in the td then is showed like a text and not like a executed code in my case a button

Comment: it's likely a syntax error. ensure it's in a `td` element not "loose".

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue

This was missing in the th:

data-field="action" data-formatter="actionFormatter" data-events="actionEvents" data-footer-formatter="footerFormatter"

Thanks to all of you for trying and have a nice and healthy holidays :)

Answer (score 0):

Changes I made:

- the tag `<form>` encapsulate whole `<table>`
- the `$id` moved out of the `action` of the form and put it as one of hidden inputs
- extracted the `<table>` from the `echo`, it is all html only
- created missing `<tbody>`
- moved all `hidden` inputs into the last table data now contains all `hidden` inputs, the `$id`,
- more over I played with code indentation at the beginning of the rows and semicolons `;` et the end of php statements

Note: the `$id` is not defined in your piece of code
Note2: you may have to play with unique identifiers of submitted row

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<table 
    id="table1" 
    data-toggle="table"
    data-search="false"
    data-filter-control="true" 
    data-show-export="false"
    data-click-to-select="false"
    data-toolbar="#toolbar"
    data-show-columns="false"
    data-checkbox-header="false"
    data-pagination="true"
    data-show-pagination-switch="false"
        
    data-show-refresh="false"
    data-show-toggle="false"
    data-sort-name="name"
    data-sort-order="desc"

    data-actions="edit,remove"
    data-url="index.php"
>  
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="id"></th>
            <th data-field="dst" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Davčna št.</th>
            <th data-field="davcna" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Ime in priimek</th>
            <th data-field="imepriimek" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Vloga v postopku</th>
            <th data-field="vloga" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Oblika pomoči</th>
            <th data-field="oblikapomoci" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Leto uvedbe postopka</th>
            <th data-field="vsebina" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="false">Vsebina</th>
            <th data-field="moznosti"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM ff_ppomoc WHERE idupor != 0 ORDER BY id ASC";

if ($result1 = $mysqli->query($query1)) {
    while ($row = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
        $field1name = $row["ime"];
        $field2name = $row["priimek"];
        $field3name = $row["ravenpomoci"];
        $field4name = $row["dst"];
        $field5name = $row["idupor"]; 
        $field6name = $row["vlogavpostopku"]; 
        $field7name = $row["id"]; 
        $field8name = $row["oblikapomoci"]; 
        $field9name = $row["letouvedbepostopka"]; 
        $field10name = $row["povzetek"]; 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $field7name; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $field4name; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $field1name; ?>  <?php echo $field2name; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $field6name; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $field8name; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $field9name; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $field10name; ?></td>
            <td>
                <?php $td1 = $_POST['td_1']; ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="<?php echo $field7name; ?>">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i><?php echo $field7name; ?></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
      <?php
  
    }
    $result->free();
}
?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```